# Mozilla Rhino 1_7r4 reference error

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am using the Rhino version (see title of this post), the log function should work I wonder if I have the right version. Was the log.* object deprecated?

Error:

```
java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
js> log.info('hello world')
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "log" is not defined.
```

I've checked `console.log('hello world')` as well. But it doesn't seem to be defined either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall Rhino providing *log* or *console* global objects. Neither are standard.

The globals provided by that shell are defined by `org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global` if memory serves. They're documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell#Predefined_Properties).

You probably want the *print* function:

> **print([expr ...])**
>
> Evaluate and print expressions. Evaluates each expression, converts
>   the result to a string, and prints it.